# Copying a file with gsutil while appending a Datetime

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I need to copy a gs file named "myfile.csv" to another file "myfile_[datetime].csv" where `datetime` is the date and time the operation occurred.

I was wondering how to do it with the gsutil.

Comment: `gsutil` cannot do that for you. Depending on the operating system, you can use command-line argument expansion/replacement, shell scripts and/or command-line tools to generate the desired filename format. There are many datetime formats. When creating a question, clearly specify the problem, the objective, the environment and show your work to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned from the comment above:

> `gsutil` cannot do that for you. Depending on the operating system, you can use command-line argument expansion/replacement, shell scripts and/or command-line tools to generate the desired filename format.

Posting OP's solution as an answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

dt=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
gsutil cp gs://myfolder/myfile.csv gs://myfolder/myfile2_$dt.csv
```